# Проблема работоспособности preg_match с большим количеством записей

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, curl

Доброго времени суток.

Помогите разобраться с регуляркой. Через curl получил страницу в переменную $page. 
В переменной содержится примерно следующее

```
<div id="middleContent">
  <div class="right-content">
    <div>
      <div id="labelRussianUL">
        <h3 style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">...</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="textRussianUL" style="display: none;">
        <p>1. Запись 1</p>
        <p>2. Запись 2</p>
        <p>3. Запись 3</p>
        ...
        где то 100
        ...
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
      <div id="labelRussianFL">
        <h3 style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">...</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="textRussianFL" style="display: none;">
        <p>1. Запись 1</p>
        <p>2. Запись 2</p>
        <p>3. Запись 3</p>
        ...
        очень много записей более 5000
        ...
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Не могу понять почему

`preg_match('/<div[^>]*id="textRussianFL"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/', $page, $match);` **не работает**  `preg_match('/<div[^>]*id="textRussianUL"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/', $page, $match);` **работает**.

Регулярку проверял на сайте [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) . С небольшим кол-вом записей работает. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Зачем регулярками разбирать HTML ? В PHP есть нормальные средства для работы с DOM. http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 3):

Всего вероятнее у вас переполнение идет из-за вот этой группы

```
(.*?)
```

Сразу после этой группы у вас указан символ `<`, а в искомом `div` у вас более 5 тыс. строк вида

```
<p>1. Запись 1</p>
```

Идет постоянный перебор символов с последующий возвратом из-за несовпадений с `<` и следующими за ним символами.

Вот регулярка https://regex101.com/r/wK1aW4/1

```
/<div[^>]*?id="textRussianFL"[^>]*?>(.*?)<\/div>/s
```

которая у меня вызывает ошибку при тесте. Дебагер показывает такой результат

> Match 1 - finished in 211352 steps

И вот более сложна регулярка https://regex101.com/r/wK1aW4/2

```
/<div[^>]*?id="textRussianFL"[^>]*?>([^<]*(?:<(?!\/div>)[^<]*)*)<\/div>/s
```

которая уже у меня не вызывает ошибки. Дебагер показывает такой результат

> Match 1 - finished in 42355 steps

Comment: Попровал я вашу регулярку '/<div[^>]*?id="textRussianFL"[^>]*?>([^<]*(?:<(?!\/div>)[^<]*)*)<\/div>/s' с данными которые возвращает curl не успевает обработать по timeout. скопировал исходный код в https://regex101.com удалил половину данных со страницы которую вернул curl и кое как вернуло результат. Но выходит так что данный вариант для моего случая не подходит. Но все равно спасибо за помощь

Comment: @baggi, сделайте проще, даже не используя DOM. Найдите регуляркой только начальный div `<div[^>]*?id="textRussianFL"[^>]*?>`, а потом с помощью функции `strpos` позицию `</div>` начиная с символа следующего за найденным открывающимся тегом (найденным регуляркой). И так для всех повторений данного `div` на странице.

Comment: не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду. Найду через регулярку `<div id="textRussianFL" style="display: none;">` и закрывающийся тег `<div>`.
но мне необходимо содержимое получить.

Comment: @baggi, ни кто не отменял функцию `substr` и математические операции по нахождению длины подстроки между двумя другими найденными подстроками.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за помощь, решил пробелему с помощью

`preg_match('/<div id="textRussianFL"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/div>/us', $page, $match);`